# Limit of subspace does not span the whole vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to prove the following lemma.

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional inner product vector space. Let $\{e_i^j\}_{j=1}^{\infty} \subset V$ be a sequence of vectors in $V$ such that $e_i^j \rightarrow e^{\infty}_{i}\in V$ as $j \rightarrow \infty$ for $i=1,...,k$. Let $V_j =span\{e_1^{j},...,e_k^{j}\}$. Suppose that $V_j \neq V $ for every $j$, prove that $V_{\infty}=span\{e_1^{\infty},...,e_k^{\infty}\}\neq V$.

My thinking process is as follows. It is clear that for $k < n$, this lemma holds. Assume $k \geq n$. So for each $j$, $e_1^j= \sum_{i=2}^{k}a_i^je_{i}^j$ for some real numbers $a_i^j$'s. I was trying to take a limit on both side. Which leads to $e_1^{\infty}=\sum_{i=2}^{k} \lim_{j \rightarrow \infty}a_i^{j}e_i^{\infty}.$ Then I get stuck on here, I'm not sure whether the limit of the coeffcients converge and not sure how to proceed. Any idea or suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: What does “$e_i^j\to e_i^\infty\in V$ as $j\to\infty$” mean?

Comment: @JohnB I see no condition that $k<\dim V$. A spanning set of a subspace having dimension $d$ can have any number of elements (provided it is $\ge d$, of course).

Comment: @JohnB $k$ vectors might be linearly dependent. I think I should prove that the convergence of those k vectors , i.e., $\{e_1^{\infty},...,e_k^{\infty}\}$, are not linearly independent.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos It means we have a sequence of vectors $\{e_i^j\}_{j=1}^{\infty}$ and this sequence converge to some vector $e_i^{\infty}$ as $ j$ goes to $\infty$.

Comment: Exactly then as I said above. Simply use Gram–Schmidt, get rid of those that are not needed, and note that sublimits of orthogonal sets are orthogonal sets, and so you are done. A basic rule (avoiding the Grassmannian) is that the limit, or any submit, depends only on the set that is generated by the vectors, not on the vectors.

Comment: If I use Gram-Schmidt on $V_1$, then I get $m_1$ orthogonal vectors with $m_1 < n$. Apply Gram-Schmidt on $V_2$, then I get $m_2$ orthogonal vectors with $m_2 < n$. Apply Gram-Schmidt on $V_{\infty}$ get $m_{\infty}$ orthogonal vectors with $m_{\infty} < n$. Is this what you are saying? I didn't see why this leads to a solution. What do you mean by ''sublimits of orthogonal sets are orthogonal sets''? Sorry, I'm new to linear algebra.

Comment: @b04902072 If you are talking about convergence, than your space is more than a vector space. There must be some distance (ar, at least, some topology) in it.

Comment: Right, and $\sup_k m_k<n$ (actually it is a maximum) because of your hypothesis and because we are in the trivial case of finite-dimensional vector spaces (and that's why it is peculiar to ask about the notion of convergence). Now note that "sublimits of orthogonal sets are orthogonal sets" simply because the inner product is a continuous function: $\langle e_i^j,e_k^j\rangle \to\langle e_i^\infty,e_k^\infty\rangle$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos You are correct. V should be an inner product vector space.

Comment: @JohnB Now, I'm confused. If I apply Gram-Schmidt on $V_{\infty}$ I actually get $m_{\infty}$ orthogonal vectors with $m_{\infty} \leq n.$ Why does $m_{\infty} < n$? Also, if we apply Gram-Schmidt to each $V_j (j=1,2,3,...)$, then $V_j = span\{u_1^j,...u_{m_j}^{j}\} $ with $\{u_i^j \}_{i=1}^{m_j}$ orthogonal. And $V_{\infty} = span\{u_1^{\infty},...,u_{m_{\infty}}^{\infty}\}$. I think we don't have $u_i^j$ converges to $u_i^{\infty} as j \rightarrow \infty$ then. So I am confused by your "inner product is continous function" argument.

Comment: Your job now, some effort is needed as always. Two hints: 1) I did write "sublimits" and 2) since $\max_k m_k<n$, it would be hard to have $m_\infty=n$. As always, this is the beautiful part of the argument since we are avoiding the Grassmannian (actually, most people don't know the distance on the Grassmannian for spaces of different dimensions).